# Grammar Mistake in Jennifer Lopez Song

Tags: grammar

What is wrong with the following Jennifer Lopez's pop song ?

My Love Don't Cost a Thing

Comment: There is nothing whatsoever wrong with "my love don't cost a thing". Nothing at all. Also, this is a duplicate. Please search the site before posting.